# Count the number of Consecutive 0s in a column with SQL

Tags: sql, logic, gaps-and-islands, row-number

I have a table that contains following data:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSf5.png)

It has **balance** containing **0s** and **1s**. Required is the total number of consecutive **0s** as well the count of consecutive instances, as below.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW0Ei.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What do your results have to do with the sample data?  They seem unrelated.

Comment: Your words don't agree with your "output".

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a grouping to the `0`s by doing a cumulative sum of `1`s.  The rest is aggregation.  So, for each sequence of `0`s:

```
select min(dt), max(dt), count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(bal) over (order by dt) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where bal = 0
group by grp;
```

I'm not sure how you want to summarize this, but this solves the "hard" part of the problem.